# laravel artisan tool to generate mvc structure

Tags: php, laravel, cakephp, laravel-artisan

I used cakephp before and it comes with bake command tool that generate full MVC skeleton with complete crud functions.

Cakephp's bake console just need database to read and it automatically generate the code with command:

```
bake all --everything
```

I want to know dose atrisan have the same tool or not? And if so how can I do that?

Should I install third party packages to achieve this or Laravel artisan support by default?

I prefer laravel default tooling if its available.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would suggest you to read laravel's documentation which is nicely written. If you are familiar with cakephp you will get into laravel really fast as i assume you know more than just basics of a framework then jumping to other framework should be fairly easy process to you.

Answer (score 0):

I don' think there is a built in command like bake all in laravel. However [this library](https://github.com/squareboat/baker) seems to do what you are asking for

You can use artisan to create individual MVC components. Perhaps you could collect these in a shell script and run them all at the same time

#### Creating a controller

This will also generate the crud functions

`php artisan make:controller ControllerName`

#### Creating a model

`php artisan make:model ModelName`

Comment: `Perhaps you could collect these in a shell script and run them all at the same time` - or you could create your own artisan command which calls the other artisan commands, just like a shell script. Calling artisan commands in code is as easy as `Artisan::call('command', ['param1', 'param2', '--option1' => 123])`.

Comment: Wasn't aware of that option. Documentation for creating an artisan command can be found here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/artisan

Comment: The problem to me seems though, generating migrations and controllers from a model can be quite difficult because validation may influence the controller code, etc.